# $ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2} f(x) d x<f(2) $; Then which of the following statements must be true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, continuity

> Let $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
> $$
> \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2} f(x) d x<f(2)
> $$
> Then which of the following statements must be true?
>
> (A) $f$ must be strictly inereasing.
>
> (B) $f$ must attain a maximum value at $x=2$
>
> (C) $f$ cannot have a minimum at $x=2$
>
> (D)None of the above.

*My work*

I have taken an example and tried to solve.Like $x^{2}$. which is satisfying the condition. So I am getting option (A) as answer. But in the meantime I have also came across a counter example $|x-1|$. It also satisfies the condition but not strictly increasing.

---

**I am looking for:**

**$1$.Is there any general approach to solve the problem?
$2$.Ans of this question**

Comment: Hint:$$min\{f(x)|x\in [a,b]\}\leq\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\leq max\{f(x)|x\in [a,b]\}$$

Comment: @Khosrotash will u please elaborate?

Comment: $$min\{f(x)|x\in [0,2]\}\leq\frac{1}{2-0}\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx\leq max\{f(x)|x\in [0,2]\}$$ put it instead of $$\frac{1}{2-0}\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx\leq f(2)$$

Comment: @Khosrotash that i have understood, And already have applied,but how do i come to the solution of this problem,moreover what's the benefit of using it here?

Comment: $$max\{f(x)|x\in [0,2]\}\leq f(2)\to f(2)=max\{f(x)|x\in [0,2]\}$$

Comment: So according to you, (C) must be the answer

Comment: Yes, (C) is the answer. A little bit of experience working with integrals and summations will make the answer evident. Otherwise, you can do what @Khosrotash did.

Comment: @Khosrotash thanks a lot. Can u please tell me from where have u written that inequality? I was unaware of that though.

Comment: First mean value theorem for definite integrals,ref:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: @Khosrotash Thanks.Indeed it is a great help

Comment: $f$ can have a *local* minimum at $x=2$, just not a *global* minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easy way to see that (C) is the answer:

Assume that $f$ does have a minimum at $x=2$ and let's denote $f(2)=k$, so that $k \leq f(x) \forall x \in [0, 2]$.

Then $2k=\int_0^2 k~dx \leq \int_0^2 f(x) ~ dx \Rightarrow k =f(2) \leq \frac 12 \int_0^2f(x)~dx$, contradicting our hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet~ $ $\textbf{Lemma:}~$ *Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on a ${\textbf{metric space}}$ $S$ to $~\mathbb{R}^{k}.~$Assume that $f$ is continuous on a $~\textbf{compact subset }$ $X$ of $S$. Then the function $f$ always attends it's maximum and minimum on $X$, namely* $$~\sup(f(X)) ~\textit{ and }~\inf(f(X))$$

$\bullet~$ $\textbf{In this case:}$

The function $f$ is defined on $[0, 2]$ $\subseteq_{\mathrm{C}}$ $\mathbb{R}.$ [where $\subseteq_{\mathrm{C}}$ means compact subset]

Now by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, there exists $F$ such that
$$ F'(x) = f(x) ~\text{ for } x \in [0, 2]$$
Therefore we have
$$ \int_{0}^{2} f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{2} F'(t)dt = F(2) - F(0) $$
Now by FTC, we have that $F$ is continuous on $[0, 2]$ and differentiable on $[0, 2]$. Therefore by LMVT, we have that
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2} f(t)dt = \frac{F(2) - F(0)}{2} = F'(c) = f(c) \quad \text{for some } c \in (0, 2) $$
Now the given condition is reduced to
$$ f(c) < f(2) \quad \text{for some } c \in (0, 2) $$
Now as $f$ is continuous on $[0, 2]$, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, by our $\textbf{Lemma},$ we have
$$ \inf\{f(x) : x \in [0, 2] \} \leqslant f(x) \leqslant \sup\{f(x) : x \in [0,2] \}$$
$\circ$ But we have $f(c) < f(2)$ for some fixed $c$ $\in$ $(0,2)$, not any arbitrary $c$. Therefore we can't comment on the monotonocity of $f$. $\implies$ $(a)$ is not true.

$\circ$ As $c$ is not arbitrary, then by our $\textbf{Lemma}$ we can say that
$$ f(c) < f(2) \leqslant \sup\{f(x) : x \in [0,2] \} \quad \text{for some } c \in (0, 2)$$
But can't surely say that $f(2) = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in [0, 2] \}$ $\implies$ $(b)$ is not true.

$\circ$ By our $\textbf{Lemma}$ we have that
$$ \inf \{ f(x) : x \in [0. 2] \} \leqslant f(c) < f(2) \quad \text{for some } c \in (0, 2)  $$
Which implies $(c)$ is true.

Hence we are done!

I hope this helps @Integral Calculus.